# jQuery split td content by coma and whitespace, style and join - how to?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to split the content of my td(only one specific td, 3rd) tag which consists of the follwing for example
  4547410173833, 4902520279385 4547410364866
and i need to style each split. Code so far works for the last number sequence

**EDIT**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.dataframe td:nth-child(3)').each(function () {
    $(this).html().split(/[ ,]+/)
                  .map(what here? =>$(this).html().substr(0, $(this).html().length - 4) +
                    "<span style='font-weight: bold; font-size: 125%'>" +
                    $(this).html().substr(-4) +
                    '</span>')
  })
})
```

Need some help figuring out how to split the td, loop it and join it back together?

My idea is make

```
var splitText = $(this).html().split(/[ ,]+/)
```

Am I on the right track with this? Still I have no idea how to loop it to add the existing styling and rejoin it.

Thank You in advance!

**Edit**
I will add my html to hopefully make more sense of what I am trying:

```
    <table border="0" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th>AK ID</th>
      <th>TOODE</th>
      <th>EAN</th>
      <th>KOOD</th>
      <th>ARVE</th>
      <th>TK</th>
      <th>XML</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>413627</td>
      <td>MSI VGA PCIE16 GTX1660TI 6GB GDDR6/GTX 1660 TI ARMOR 6G OC MSI</td>
      <td>824142178560, 824142178560 824142178560</td>
      <td>GTX1660TIARMOR6GOC</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>412423</td>
      <td>GIGABYTE GeForce GTX 1660 Ti / WindForce / 6GB GDDR6</td>
      <td>4719331304447, 4718755071829</td>
      <td>GV-N166TWF2OC-6GD</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>301792</td>
      <td>ART Holder 2xLCD/LED MONITORS 13-27'' 8KG L-02A</td>
      <td>5902115405679 4711173874515</td>
      <td>RAMM L-02A</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>367459</td>
      <td>Dell P2419H 23.8 FHD LED AG 1920x1080 8ms HDMI, DP, VGA, 5xUSB, VESA/Black</td>
      <td>5397184092392</td>
      <td>210-APWU</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: You write you want to style each split, but in your code you only style the last 4 characters of the content, not the other part. Is that on purpose?

Comment: It's the only way i know so far to take the last 4 characters of the entire string and edit it. I haven't figured out how to make the entire string which is in td into as many parts as there are such number sequences seperated either by coma or space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figued it out with some help, thanks for the map and arrow function!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".dataframe td:nth-child(3)").each(function() {
    let html = $(this).html();
    let eans = html.split(/[ ,]+/)
    $(this).html(
      eans
        .map(e => `${e.substr(0, e.length - 4)}<span style='font-weight: bold; font-size: 125%'>${e.substr(-4)}</span>`)
        .join(", ")
    );
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your on the right track with:

```
$(this).html().split(/[ ,]+/)
```

You can continue like this:

```
$(this).html().split(/[ ,]+/)
              .map(part => "<span>" + part + "</span>")
              .join("")
```

Comment: Sorry, having bit difficulty following this part ".map(part => "<span>" + part + "</span>")"

Comment: Map transforms an array into a new array with the same number of elements, using the function as a rule to transform each element.  In this case, the map turns eg `["one", "two"]` into `["<span>one</span>", "<span>two</span>"]`.

Comment: Check out [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Comment: Thank You for the feedback. But this is driving me crazy, does not work. part before arrow function is an arbitrary name for each split inside map?

Comment: Edited my original question

Comment: So you added `map` to your question? Why do you do that? Please don't change your question like that? Please read the documentation of `map`. It takes a callback function with arguments. Like with every function, you choose the names of the parameters. "Does not work" is not really a helpful. It is helpful though to see the HTML in your question. Could you also add below that what the desired output is for that same HTML?